# Determine the type of a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, types, allocator

So I am making a Memory Stack Allocator that is capable of allocating any instance of any type onto the heap in a continuous fashion.

In order to do this i have added a 'AllocationHeader' class directly before each allocation which contains a void* to the instance address itself and a AllocationHeader* to the previous header.
So far this has worked perfectly and i'm able to allocate and deallocate etc.

But i've ran into 1 (possibly 2) problems. 
In order to deallocate properly I also need to call the destructor of the object in question and then remove it from the stack.
This is fine when i'm removing an instance that i have a pointer to as i can just pass it to the deallocate function and it knows what type it is and does its thing.

The problem lies when I want to create functions like deallocateAll() or deallocateAllAboveObject(T* obj) as I would need to know the types of each allocation without explicitly passing their pointer, so i could go down each allocation in the stack calling the deconstructor on each as I go.

***What I would like is to be able to create an AllocationHeader which can store a pointer of any type, and then the type of the pointer can be retrieved at a later date without already knowing the type.***

I'm really not sure how to do this as all suggestions that i've seen so far involve comparing the object with a specific type and seeing if they're the same. However I can't just check against each possible class in the program as there could be 1000's as I continue to build on this.

Alternatively if you have any suggestions for an alternative approach to a stack allocator that can deal with any type, that would be great as well.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better to post your code here instead of expaining it

Comment: You have to store the type info of each object somewhere, either store with the data or in a separate container like `std::map`

Comment: @gdlmx so far i've not got any code that's relevent to this question really, before I even tried to create something i tried to plan a little and knew i'd hit this problem. All i know is that i need a class that contains a pointer to any possible object and then i can somehow find out what the type of the pointer in the class is.

Comment: @gdlmx if I stored the type_info somewhere else how can I use that though? i'd already thought of this method but I thought it wouldn't work because whilst the type_info contains the information for a type I cant use that to (for example) convert a void* to an MyClass* without doing some type of comparision between the type_info i have and MyClass type_info. Is that right or have i got it wrong?

Comment: By type_info I mean the _constructor_ and _destructor_ of the specific type/class, as shown in the answer of @Isaac. Like this `std::unordered_map<void *, std::pair<func_ptr, func_ptr>> allocator` where `typedef void (*func_ptr)()` and the pair stores constructor and destructor function pointers, respectively. Then you can destroy the object by `allocator[p].second(p);`

Comment: @gdlmx thank you, thats really helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to C++'s static type system, I can only see a couple of solutions to the problem

- Make every type you use with the allocator derive from a (consistent) type with a virtual distructor e.g. `struct destructible { virtual ~destructible() { } }`, however this will potentially enlarge & alter the layout of any types you alter to derive from this.

Or uppon allocation store a function object that does the destruction, e.g. using the following template

```
template<typename T> void destroy(void* p) { reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)->T::~T(); }

struct AllocationHeader
{
    template<typename T> AllocationHeader(AllocationHeader* previouse, void* data)
        : previouse(previouse), data(data), destructor(&destroy<T>) { }
    AllocationHeader* previouse;
    void* data;
    void (*destructor)(void*);
}
void deallocateAll(AllocationHeader& start)
{
    for (AllocationHeader* a = &start; a != nullptr; a = start->previouse;)
    {
        a->destructor(a->data);
        delete a->data;
    }
}
```

(Without providing your code for the `AllocationHeader` type it is difficuilt to help you.)

Note: My compiler/IDE is currently reinstalling so I am unable to test the above code, I am pretty sure about most of it, except I may need to put a `typename` in the destructor call syntax `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p).T::~T();`

**EDIT** Using a template constructor, where the template arguments cannot be inferred is a bad idea, the following constructor should be used instead

```
AllocationHeader(AllocationHeader* previouse, void* data, void(*destructor)(void*))
        : previouse(previouse), data(data), destructor(destructor) { }
```

Just pass `&destroy<T>` as the 3rd argument to it.

Comment: Okay, if i'm understanding correctly is void(*)(void*) destructor simply a pointer to destructor function of type T?

Comment: @LukeBourne er yes, but my syntax is wrong (unfortunately the C/C++ syntax for function pointers is utterly ridiculous and confusing),
it should be `void(*destructor)(void*)`

Comment: Okay I think this will actually work! :) I will test it out later but i think this is a good solution at least for my current problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, i've hit a deadend. how I call the constructor on AllocationHeader to create new headers? **AllocationHeader* cHeader = new(address) AllocationHeader::AllocationHeader<T>(lastAllocation, address);** and **AllocationHeader* cHeader = new(address) AllocationHeader<T>(lastAllocation, address);** produces errors :/

Comment: @Luke what errors? Also you do realise that code will construct a new AllocationHeader at 'address' with 'data = this'? Seems kind of odd...

Comment: sorry, the errors still occur with `new AllocationHeader<T>(lastAllocation, address);` (i was using placement new to allocate to preallocated memory, just assume its plain old new for the purpose of this) and i get: **error C2061: syntax error: identifier '{ctor}'** when I use `new AllocationHeader::AllocationHeader<T>(lastAllocation, address);` and **error C2512: 'ClassHeader': no appropriate default constructor available** when i use `new AllocationHeader<T>(lastAllocation, address);`

Comment: @LukeBourne sorry about that, now that I have access to a compiler again I see the problem, I have updated my answer to correct it,

Using my new constructor you would use:
`new(address) AllocationHeader(lastAllocation, address, &destroy<T>)`

Comment: @LukeBorune one other thing, I am a bit worried about taking the address of a template function, I am uncertain as to whether it is undefined or not.

Comment: @Isaac why would it be undefined?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I was thinking in the case where it would be in a header file, and so It may be declared multiple times in the same compilation unit (but only once per translation unit ofcourse)... but I'm probably wrong

Comment: @Isaac depends if it's a template prototype that gets instantiated in one translation unit for use in others or a full template function definition. But yeah, there's nothing undefined about the function being instantiated separately in different translation units.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I'll take your word for it, I was just worried.

Comment: @Isaac Hey i'm still getting the same errors unfortunately. I've added a new answer with my code because it wouldn't fit in this comment box. Thank you.

Comment: @isaac Ignore the last comment, i found a slight work around where i made a 'createClassHeader()' static function that used a non templated constructor to create a class header and then I initiliased the *destructor after. This worked and i finally got everything working. Whats more, by doing your method i figured out another problem i was predicting i would encounter. So thank you! :) its been a big help.